# What does this mean "^3.0.0-0" in package.json?

Tags: package.json

I don't understand what this hyphen means in package.json.

I know the hyphen is usually used like "version1 - version2 Same as >=version1 <=version2".

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

**package.json**

```
"@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-0",
```

https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/blob/master/template/_package.json

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the hyphen indicates [prerelease tags](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#prerelease-tags), such as 3.0.0-beta.0. Although it isn't documented anywhere that I've found, I believe the use of `-0` as a prerelease tag says "accept any prerelease version". So this will accept any prerelease of 3.0.0.

There is a [tool on the NPM website](https://semver.npmjs.com/) that allows you to see what versions are accepted by a semantic version range.

Comment: Thanks, lonesomeday! As you expected, when I tried to install the package with the hyphen version range, the latest prerelease version was installed. Next, I set as `"@nuxtjs/pwa": "^2.0.0-0"`. Then, version 2.6.0 was installed. From the result and your help, for now, I can suppose that `-0` can install prerelease and released latest version.